# Asp.Net Dropdownlist SelectedIndexChanged in update panel, even when <Triggers> used

Tags: asp.net

Can anyone tell me why is this not working? I have searched everywhere already.
Usually when I do this, it works without triggers.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
        <div style="width:15%;float:left;">

            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Img/Untitled1.png" CssClass="imagez" />

        </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <div style="width:85%;float:left;height:100%;padding-top:2%;">

            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="CPU" CssClass="auto-style7" Font-Names="sans-serif"></asp:Label>
            <br />

            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="bla" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" Font-Names="sans-serif" EnableViewState="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Pick a CPU</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

This is the code for `SelectedIndexChanged`:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label2.Text = "please";
}
```

Comment: You forgot to mention what exactly is not working

Comment: The selectedindexchanged event is not firing!

Comment: There is only one `ListItem`. There is nothing that can change.

Comment: No, there is more than one! i if you look closely, i actually wrote DataSourceID.

Comment: Sorry, didn't scroll far enough to the right. But I tested your code and it works like it should. The problem is not in the above snippet.

Comment: I placed a break-point in my SelectedIndexChanged code, and it seems like it is not being run at all. Like the entire thing. Please help!

Comment: I tested that and selectedindexchanged fired! Did you use ScriptManager?

Comment: @Nicholas you can try my answer below. Moving the label inside update panel will work

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose the `Label2` control inside the update panel content template as below otherwise, it won't get refreshed with the new value.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
        <div style="width:15%;float:left;">

            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Img/Untitled1.png" CssClass="imagez" />

<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="CPU" CssClass="auto-style7" Font-Names="sans-serif"></asp:Label>
            <br />

        </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <div style="width:85%;float:left;height:100%;padding-top:2%;">



            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="bla" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" Font-Names="sans-serif" EnableViewState="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Pick a CPU</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

*Note*: 1. If it still didn't work, along with the above code, try removing the `EventName` as below from the trigger

```
<Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </Triggers>
```

2. If it still didn't work, remove the `CssClass="bla"` from the dropdown and try if it changes any behavior of dropdown on the client side

Answer (score 0):

You want to change a label that is out of updatepanel. And its not logic.
If you move the Label2 to

```
<asp:UpdatePanel><ContentTemplateit>
```

it will work. (I tested)